# Reading full rows in Java ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I know there are similar questions to this one, but I haven't found any answer anywhere. For some reason ResultSet has no function to read the full row to a String or similar object, so there's a need to make up tricky workarounds to read full rows and it always involves column-by-column processing.

The question is - what would be the preferred way to do this?
An example query - `SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM table WHERE this=that`.
I want to add each row of this query to a List< String> and return the List when it's completed.
Currently all I can think of is reading each column, concatenating it to a String and then adding the String to the List, and this for each row.
The problem is that IMHO this makes up for quite excessive code when it could be done in ResultSet alone.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: A ResultSet is for row-based access to tabular data. Tabular data is inherently two-dimensional, therefore you always have columns, unless you concatenate ni the database already.

Comment: What should an element in the List<String> be?  If you just want all the values mushed together then I believe Vincents solution will work.  Would you rather have some sort of comma-separated String or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL to [concatenate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the results for you like this:

```
 SELECT concat(a, b, c, d, e) as mysinglestringcolumn from table
```

Then in your resultset you have only a single column to deal with.